# System.AccessViolationException due a System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery

Tags: entity-framework, access-violation

From time to time I'm getting an Exception of the type System.AccessViolationException in my w3wp.exe that crash the app.

The stack of the exception is this (got from the event viewer):

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          05-04-2013 00:00:27
Event ID:      1026
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MYSERVER
Description:
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]..ctor()
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.CoordinatorScratchpad..ctor(System.Type)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.ProcessCollectionColumnMap(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.CollectionColumnMap, System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.TranslatorArg, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap, System.Object)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.Visit(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap, System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.TranslatorArg)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.SimpleCollectionColumnMap.Accept[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.TranslatorArg, System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapVisitorWithResults`2<System.__Canon,System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.TranslatorArg>, System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.TranslatorArg)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Translator.TranslateColumnMap[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Data.Common.QueryCache.QueryCacheManager, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace, System.Data.Objects.Internal.SpanIndex, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ShaperFactory+TypedShaperFactoryCreator`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].TypedCreate(System.Data.Common.QueryCache.QueryCacheManager, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace, System.Data.Objects.Internal.SpanIndex, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ShaperFactory.Create(System.Type, System.Data.Common.QueryCache.QueryCacheManager, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace, System.Data.Objects.Internal.SpanIndex, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption, Boolean)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree, System.Type, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption, System.Data.Objects.Span, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter,System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression>>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Boolean>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Boolean>)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Boolean>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Linq.IQueryable`1<System.__Canon>)
   at MY.WebService.NetworkValidation.ValidIp(System.String)
   at MY.WebService.SedeService.IsLogged(MY.DataBase.SedeData.User)
   at MY.WebService.Sede.IsLogged()
   at DynamicClass.SyncInvokeIsLogged(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[] ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnContinueAsyncReceive(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

The code of the function ValidIp(string ip) (last function that I call before get the exception):

```
try
{                
    using(var db = new AccessEntities())
    {
        var ret = db.AccessControl.Where(xx => xx.Ip == ip && xx.IsValid).Any();                    
        return ret;
    }
}
catch (Exception ee)
{                
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening ? I call this function every 1h and from times to times give this exception, last time took 2 days and half to happen, another interesting thing is I'm doing a try/catch shouldn't I be able to catch the exception and prevent the w3wp.exe crash ?

Thanks in advance,
Rui

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the CLR or IIS host for ASP.NET (or broken installation - non-matching components etc.). Have you tried moving to .NET Framework 4.5? The bug might have been fixed in a newer release. Consider reporting this bug back to Microsoft - I am afraid there might not be an easy fix for this.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser Pawel. I will try contact Microsoft about this.

Comment: Pawel should I contact MS by connect.micrososft.com ? If yes which product should I choose ? Sql Server related ? Thanks